Are questions about the history of quantitative finance in scope?
Prompted by this question:

What is the origin of the words “put” and “call” that characterize derivatives?

The following questions, posted by a moderator, seems to have gotten a relatively warm reception.


Who has introduced the term 'vega' and why?
Option pricing before Black-Scholes


There may be a difference, here, in that the latter questions are very quant-specific, whereas the new question concerns general knowledge, but I am unsure.
However, I fear that allowing too many of these types of questions detracts from the site.  Plus these questions may be welcome on money.SE, so there may be no need to answer them here.
This previous meta question may also be relevant here:

Are questions about financial institutions on-topic?


The two questions you mention were the primary motivation for asking the put/call & short/long question. I was unaware of the money.se branch. Why do you think they're appropriate there and not here?

History questions can be OK provided

they don't overrun the site
they are truly on-topic and specialized for quant
they solicit answers backed by research and citations, not opinions

Based on the list in the Q, I think 2/3 are OK, the "put and call" one is too generic and broad to work.

My question is apparently the third on the site. I can't think of something more relevant to quants, than to know why they name things that way. The question does not preclude citations similar to those given in who has introduced vega and why, or that on what was used before B&S -- whose answers, I might add, have more of a guestimate character.

I don't think these types of questions are relevant to the site.
